# Dvorak input mode wrong letters when typing fast, correct, when typing slow

Tags: evil, doom, input-method, keyboard-layout

I have dvorak keyboard layout set as input when I am in evil-input mode. However, when I type relatively fast when typing `the` I get `thd`. This is just an example, some other "typos" occur as well. This doesn't occur, however, when I am typing slowly.

I would assume this happens because in dvorak layout `e` is where letter `d` is in the standard layout (i.e. somehow emacs doesn't manage to remap it).

How can I prevent such typos from occurring?

My config is:

```
(after! evil
  (setq evil-escape-key-sequence "hk")

  (add-hook! 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook
    (activate-input-method "english-dvorak")))
```

Comment: Emacs seem like an unlikely culprit to me.  There are many other possibilities.  It's my hunch that hardware or the operating system (or whatever application handles input) are more likely causes.  Are you sure you don't get misstrokes when typing in Qwerty?   Does the problem occur with other keyboards?  What is your operating system?